# gcal drupal 7 change sharing settings

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, google-calendar-api

I was wondering if it is possible to change the sharing settings in drupal 7 programmatically via the gcal API as described [here.](http://drupal.org/project/gcal) I noticed that there is a function with gcal_setting_get() which retrieves the settings but I'm not sure how to edited the sharing settings for each calendar that I make on the account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by "sharing settings"?  Do you want to make the calendar public or to share it with some other user. if yes then you just need to create a acl for that. you can make use of gcal_acl_create function of the module.  For more reference of these functions you can check EXAMPLES.txt file in the module.

Hth,
Sadashiv.